# Attempted install of Python 3 via homebrew fails on Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install Python 3 alongside 2.7 with Homebrew but am receiving an error message I can't find a resolution to.

When attempting `brew update && brew install python3` I get the following error:

```
Error: python 2.7.12_2 is already installed
To upgrade to 3.6.4_3, run `brew upgrade python`
```

I want to leave the python 2.7 installation alone so I can have both Python 2 & 3 accessible on my machine so I'm nervous that upgrading will overwrite the current 2.7 installation.

I figure I can still perform a clean side-by-side install with the package from python.org, but I want to know why I'm getting this homebrew error

`brew doctor` shows the following Warnings containing python

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: Some installed formulae are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:
  brew install python@2
```

Comment: Did you run `brew doctor`?

Comment: I have two warnings that mention python. 1st: `Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` and 2nd: `Warning: Some installed formulae are missing dependencies.`, one of which is `python@2`. Would either of these warnings cause a failure to install python3?

Comment: What happens when you type `which python` and `python --version`?

Comment: Can you run `brew install python` and `brew install python3` ? Do you get the same output for both? Do they both recommend running `brew upgrade python` ?

Comment: @A. J Alger -`which python` outputs `/usr/local/bin/python` and `python -V` outputs `Python 2.7.12`

Comment: @AK47 yes, both output the same thing

Comment: @A.J.Alger also i lied, there's another mention of python in brew doctor. I've updated the question

Comment: You have already install Python via an installer. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Try using pyenv

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, and what I also have on my own system, is Python 3 as the default and Python 2 available if I need it. With homebrew, you can just update your default as it wants you to do with the upgrade. That means when you run `python`, Python 3 will run as the default.

For Python 2, install `brew install python@2`. When you want to run Python 2, just run `python2` in the terminal and you'll have it.

Answer (score 0):

Python install will run once you fix the broken links by running brew link, and the missing link component.
These usually don't need SUDO, they will link then and run brew doctor once they have all been linked.